# Grub menu no showing after upgrading ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, fedora

I had Ubuntu and Fedora in different drives in dual boot mode, but after I upgraded Ubuntu , the grub menu is not showing and directly boot into Ubuntu so I can't boot into my Fedora.

Any solutions, thank you.

Comment: Install Grub customizer and edit the settings.

Comment: in order to better help you with this, and, possibly, other boot problems in the future, it can be really helpful to specify the kind of firmware your computer implements (whether is _PC/BIOS_ or _UEFI_), also the "bitness" your CPU and OS supports. (where is 32 or 64 bits or the specific architecture if you know it). I also need to know if you have *aptitude* package installed for it really helps to check for installed packages. unfortunately, for some reason, latest versions of Ubuntu don't come with this package installed by default `sudo apt-get install aptitude` should do the magic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you tried holding shift down while booting? It should display the Grub menu if Grub is installed.

I suppose it's also possible Grub got somehow removed but I don't think that should happen in Ubuntu upgrades.

Unfortunately I'm not a Grub expert, so if the above doesn't help, I can only point you to this Community Wiki page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2